# Reed switches in parallel

Tags: switches

I am replacing a reed switch in a device that failed open, I can only assume due to lack of use; is it worth putting two in parallel as a failsafe, or is that just a pointless pre-optimisation and they're likely to fail together anyway?

If it matters, the device is a fully watertight light that uses a movable magnet on an external slider as the switch.

Comment: Depends. If one fail open then it helps. If one fail to short you have worse redundancy than before. Which are you trying to protect yourself against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question, one would need detailed information about the application. You should consider the potential failure modes (failing open / failing closed / both switches failing together), what the effects of these failures would be, and the potential consequences of the failures. Wether they are likely to fail together is fully dependant on what might cause the switch to fail in the first place.

As an example, say you install two switches. Now, you have added redundancy for one of the switches failing *open*, allowing you to still turn the light on. However, you have increased the probability of a switch failing *closed*, potentially draining the battery while the light is in storage.

This kind of analysis is called a Failure Mode Effects and Criticality Analysis (FMECA). While a full analysis is probably wildely overkill for a flashlight, if this light is intended for use in an emergency, it would be a good idea to think through potential failures.

As a final note, you could also consider the effort needed to replace the switch if it breaks again. It might be easier to just replace it again, rather than modifying the design to add a redundant switch.

Comment: Have marked this the answer because it made me stop and think properly about the use-case; in my case it's much more important it switches on reliably than it is that it doesn't switch on in storage, so I have gone for the two in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace one, I don't think you need redundancy, as you say maybe the previuous one fail for lack of use.

In a theoretical way I will not put two of them in parallel because they never switch at the same time and depending of the electronic you are switching the switch signal will be a double bounce.
Note: As soon as the first switch does close action of the second is irrelevant. Therefore the added bounce may not be relevant especially assuming the time difference between the two switches closing is longer than the bounce period (due to their different thresholds and exposure to magnetic field).

For power switching purpose there is no problem.